# Having problem web scraping drop down menus that don't show up when you inspect them

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape data from https://chanakyya.com/Election-Results?electionType=Assembly.
I want to scrape for Uttar Pradesh-->Ajgara(SC)-->polling booths. I want to scrape all polling booths for Uttar Pradesh-->Ajgara(SC) but when I inspect the website to get class or id it shows only state dropdown menu.
The code so far gives the table for Uttar Pradesh only:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
import choice

states = requests.get('https://chanakyya.com/Chanakya/states.json').json()

state_list = [x['stateDisplayName'] for x in states]
state_choice = choice.Menu(state_list).ask()

stateName = [x['stateName'] for x in states if x['stateDisplayName'] == state_choice][0]

url = f'https://chanakyya.com/Chanakya/{stateName}/{stateName}.json'
resultsData = requests.get(url).json()

tables = {}
for key, value in resultsData['ELECTION_DATA']['stateLevelData'].items():
    table = pd.DataFrame(value)
    tables[key] = table

for key, table in tables.items():
    print(f'*** {key} ***')
    print(table)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there code what you've tried so far?

Comment: @AndrejKesely done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url_1 = "https://chanakyya.com/Chanakya/UttarPradesh/AssemblyData/Ajagara_(SC).json?isNewDataFormat=true"
data = requests.get(url_1).json()
url_2 = (
    "https://chanakyya.com/Chanakya/UttarPradesh/BoothData/"
    + data["ELECTION_DATA"]["boothFileName"]
)
data = requests.get(url_2).json()

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     Party Assembly Cons No  Year Election Type                           Candidate Name Total rank                         Locality/Pooling Booth Vote polled
0      BJP              385  2014    Parliament                  DR MAHENDRA NATH PANDEY   731    1                               P.P.CHAMAV R.NO1         519
1       SP              385  2014    Parliament                                RAMKISHUN   731    2                               P.P.CHAMAV R.NO1          70
2      BSP              385  2014    Parliament                        ANIL KUMAR MAURYA   731    3                               P.P.CHAMAV R.NO1          56
3      AAP              385  2014    Parliament                                   IRSHAD   731    4                               P.P.CHAMAV R.NO1          23
4      INC              385  2014    Parliament   TARUN PATEL URF TARUNENDRA CHAND PATEL   731    5                               P.P.CHAMAV R.NO1           9

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrej Kesely it was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Check in network tab of inspect, you will find this [url](https://chanakyya.com/Chanakya/UttarPradesh/AssemblyData/Alapur_(SC).json?isNewDataFormat=true) which has the json for list of polling booths

Hope so this will solve your issue

Comment: Thank you @Tejas for trying to help